# What is the easy way to access the callback function arguments outside of it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

My code is like this,

```
var jenkins = require('jenkins')('http://192.168.1.5:8080');
var job_name = undefined;

jenkins.job.list(function doneGetting(err, list) {
    if (err) throw err;
    job_name = list[0].name;
});

jenkins.job.get(job_name, function(err, info){
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('index', {
         title: 'Jenkins API',
         job_name: job_name,
         job_info: info
    })
});
```

My problem is I am not able to get the value of job_name because it is inside the callback.
I am trying to find the solution for this. Though lot of questions already present about callbacks am not able to find the solution. Sorry for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply move your `jenkins.job.get` inside `jenkins.job.list` callback

```
jenkins.job.list(function doneGetting(err, list) {
    if (err) throw err;
    job_name = list[0].name;

    jenkins.job.get(job_name, function(err, info){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('index', {
             title: 'Jenkins API',
             job_name: job_name,
             job_info: info
        })
    });
});
```

there are other solutions, like to use a function

```
jenkins.job.list(function doneGetting(err, list) {
    if (err) throw err;
    job_name = list[0].name;

    getJob(job_name);
});

function getJob(job_name) {
    jenkins.job.get(job_name, function(err, info){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('index', {
             title: 'Jenkins API',
             job_name: job_name,
             job_info: info
        })
    });
}
```

it depends by your pattern, or module or script complexity.

Comment: Thank you chumkiu, second solution looks good. I think also I have to learn about 'async'.

Comment: You're welcome :) try to take a look here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/